# Rails - Nested form not showing - fill table without another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I am new to rails and struggling at the moment with nested forms.

I simply want to allow a business to come to the site and register their business details in a single form. At the database level I have split address information away from the 'businesses' table and put it in its own 'addresses' table because 'users' will also have an address registers in the system.

The form view looks like this:

```
<div class= "panel-body">   
    <%= form_for(@business) do |f| %>

        <div class= "form-group">
    <%= f.label :Business_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true,  class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

      <div class= "form-group">
        <%= f.label :Business_Email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email,  class: "form-control" %>
      </div>


      <div class= "form-group">
      <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |x| %>
        <%= x.label :Street_Number %>
        <%= x.text_field :number %>
      <% end %>
        </div>

        <div class= "form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Register", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I have a feeling it has to do with nothing being instantiated for addresses to bother rendering anything however it seems like overkill to give addresses a controller of its own.

The business controller looks like this for 'new' which is the URL for registering a new business.

```
GET /businesses/new
  def new
    @business = Business.new
    ***Do I need to add something here for address?***
  end
```

I am pretty sure the relationships for the models are correct:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :business
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields won't render if there are no addresses associated with `@business`.

Add this to your controller:

```
GET /businesses/new
def new
  @business = Business.new
  @business.addresses.build
end
```

Comment: Thank you! knew it would be something simple.

Comment: Perhaps you could help with one more similar issue. I am getting an "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass" error when doing this for another nested form I would like in the form. I am doing as you suggested above. This time with 'template' instead of 'addresses'. The only difference is the business has only one template (template -> belongs_to business, business -> has_one template) instead of the many relationships. Would this require something different in the syntax?

Comment: It works very similarly, but since it is `has_one` association you need to use `build_template`, not `template.build`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize an empty address object in new action

```
  def new
    @business = Business.new
    @business.addresses.new
  end
```

If you want to have more than 1 address fields, you could do

```
2.times { @business.addresses.new } # This will initialize 2 address objects, which will be seen on the form
```